# Why is the segmentation fault showing even after memory allocation?

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

The code shows the segmentation fault in the function free_nlist()(line#539) within the nlist.c file.

I tried one thing but I do not think that it was logical; I tried allocating the dynamic memory to the variable "nlb_head"(line #542) using the command :
 nlb_head = (struct nlblock *) malloc( sizeof( struct nlblock ) );
It did give me the results but can anyone explain as to whether this is correct or not.

```
void free_nlist( struct nlblock *nlb_head )  
{                                            
    struct nlblock  *nlb_tmp;                
    nlb_tmp=NULL;                            
    while( nlb_head != NULL )                
    {   
      nlb_tmp = nlb_head->next;              
      free( nlb_head );                       
      nlb_head = nlb_tmp;                    
    }                                          
    free(nlb_tmp);                             
}
```

The link to the code is given below:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BDP-gkSP9rPvAM4oVdNYmwmJqPhy3o_w

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: If `nlb_head != NULL` is false then freeing not dynamically allocated/assigned memory `free(nlb_tmp);` is wrong. This `free(nlb_tmp);` should be done with check `nlb_tmp != NULL`

Comment: @Achal free(NULL) is well defined, even if it is unnecessary.

Comment: As pointed out by @Achal, the call `free(nlb_tmp);` at the end of the function is wrong. Unless `free_nlist` is called with a null pointer, the final element of the list will be freed twice, once in the loop and once at the end of the function. Just remove the final call `free(nlb_tmp);` to fix the problem.

Comment: The code is correct. The last `free(nlb_tmp);` after the loop is useless, but after the loop `nlb_tmp == NULL` so it is harmless. But if the linked list has been corrupted before entering this part of code, you could try to free non allocated blocs and get that error. TL/DR: the error is likely to be in not shown code.

Comment: @SergeBallesta@IanAbbott I tried removing the free(nlb_tmp) but somehow the same problem of segmentation fault exists.

Comment: Please ask a self contained question with reproducible example. Link to a huge code base in GDrive will not get you far..